# JavaFx: Bind TableView's and ScrollPane's scrollBars

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scrollbar, bind

I'm trying to bind somehow a `TableView`'s scrolling to a `ScrollPane`'s scrolling.
I could get a reference from both scrollbars but I couldn't bind them. 
I found also that the values of scrollbars are different,
the `TableView`'s scrollbar has values between 0 and 100 while the `Scrollpane`'s has values between 0 and 1.

Here is that I've tried so far:

How I got the reference:

```
private static ScrollBar getScrollBar(Control source) {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = null;
        for (Node node : source.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(Orientation.HORIZONTAL)) {
                scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
            }
        }
        return scrollBar;
}
```

Then:

```
public static void bindScrollBars(ScrollPane scrollPane, TableView<?> table) {
        ScrollBar scrollBarPane = getScrollBar(scrollPane);
        ScrollBar scrollBarTable = getScrollBar(table);
        scrollBarPane.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(scollBarTable.valueProperty())
}
```

This way works the binding itself but I need to bind multiplied or divided by 100 to scale them to the same level.
If I try to add `.multyply(100)` or `.divide(100)` won't work for obvious reasons, but I have no idea how can I bind them bidirectional while scaling them to the same level or 0..100 or 0..1.
Can you suggest any solution?

The second question would be if I would get a solution to the previous one, then how could I bind more than two `Control`'s scrollbars? For instance if I have 4 `Control`s (ScrollPane, TableView, TreeTableView, TreeTableView), how can I ensure that all of those components' scollbars are bound to each other?

P.S. If I try to don't use bidirectional binding just bind for example :

```
scrollBarPane.valueProperty().bind(scrollBarTable.valueProperty().divide(100));
```

I get a RuntimeException, with the message: `ScrollBar.value: A bound value cannot be set.`

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584523/8722066) solution?

Comment: Hmm yes, that solves my first problem, but when I try to bind several Controls using this it seems it is not working.