# Synchronize scrollbars of two JavaFx WebViews

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-8

I'm using two `WebView`s to display two versions of HTML formatted text for comparison. The two display the same amount of text (same number of lines and corresponding lines have always the same length).

When the displayed text exceeds the size of the node, the WebView gets scroll bars. Of course I want these scroll bars to scroll synchronously so that always the corresponding text is displayed.

In order to supply a minimal, complete and verifiable example, I trimmed the code down to this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SynchronizedWebViewsTest extends Application {

  protected class DifferencePanel extends GridPane {
    private WebView actualPane;
    private WebView expectedPane;

    public DifferencePanel() {
      setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
      actualPane = new WebView();
      expectedPane = new WebView();
      setResultPanes();
      addRow(0, actualPane, expectedPane);
    }

    public void setHtml(WebView webView) {
      Platform.runLater(() -> {
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(createHtml());
      });
    }

    public void synchronizeScrolls() {
      final ScrollBar actualScrollBarV = (ScrollBar)actualPane.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
      final ScrollBar expectedScrollBarV = (ScrollBar)expectedPane.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
      actualScrollBarV.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(expectedScrollBarV.valueProperty());
      final ScrollBar actualScrollBarH = (ScrollBar)actualPane.lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");
      final ScrollBar expectedScrollBarH = (ScrollBar)expectedPane.lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");
      actualScrollBarH.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(expectedScrollBarH.valueProperty());
    }

    private String createHtml() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("<nobr>%03d %2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s</nobr><br/>\n",
                                Integer.valueOf(i), "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "));
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }

    private void setResultPanes() {
      setHtml(actualPane);
      setHtml(expectedPane);
    }
  } // ---------------------------- end of DifferencePanel ----------------------------


  public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage dummy)  throws Exception {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    DifferencePanel differencePanel = new DifferencePanel();
    Scene scene = new Scene(differencePanel);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    differencePanel.synchronizeScrolls();
    stage.showAndWait();
  }
}
```

I tried using adding a listener:

```
actualScrollBarV.onScrollFinishedProperty().addListener(event -> {
  System.out.println(event);
});
```

But the listener is never invoked.

I'm using Java version 1.8.0_92, but with version 9.0.4 I get the same result.

Can anybody tell me, what I'm missing here?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are referring to **completeness**.
My hope was that someone else had done that and could help, but I'll supply a complete test case as soon as I've found the time to trim the code down to the relevant part.

Comment: at last :)) Could not find a solution, but the reason neither the binding nor the listener are doing anything is that each pane has 3 (vertical) scrollBars of which the "last" (iterating over the set returned from lookupAll) seems to be the active one. Binding those doesn't help: the second value is updated, but has no visible effect - and the value is reverted when moving the mouse over the bar ... weird, probably needs some digging deep in the bowels ..

Comment: Ah, so I was not yet digging deep enough. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the `ScrollBar` approach working. It turned out that the listeners were actually invoked (breakpoints in lambdas are not always working?). Setting the scroll bar value of the other `WebView` did not get it inclined change the scroll bar or the view port. :-(

There is something strange going on with events in `WebView`; that might be because there is a native library involved...

---

However, the approach using the event handler of `WebView` works. The event handler of each `WebView` simply mirrors all events to the other `WebView`, using a synchronizing field `Boolean scrolling` to avoid recursion.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class SynchronizedWebViewsTest extends Application {

      protected class DifferencePanel extends GridPane {
        private Boolean scrolling = Boolean.FALSE;
        private WebView actualPane;
        private WebView expectedPane;

        public DifferencePanel() {
          setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
          actualPane = new WebView();
          expectedPane = new WebView();
          setResultPanes();
          addRow(0, actualPane, expectedPane);
        }

        public void setHtml(WebView webView) {
          Platform.runLater(() -> {
            webView.getEngine().loadContent(createHtml());
          });
        }

        public void synchronizeScrolls() {
          wireViews(actualPane, expectedPane);
          wireViews(expectedPane, actualPane);
        }

        private void wireViews(WebView webView, WebView otherWebView) {
          webView.addEventHandler(Event.ANY, event -> {
            if (!scrolling.booleanValue()) {
              synchronized (scrolling) {
                scrolling = Boolean.TRUE;
                if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                  MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
                  Point2D origin = webView.localToScreen(0, 0);
                  Point2D otherOrigin = otherWebView.localToScreen(0, 0);
                  double offsetX = otherOrigin.getX() - origin.getX();
                  double offsetY = otherOrigin.getY() - origin.getY();
                  double x = mouseEvent.getX();
                  double y = mouseEvent.getY();
                  double screenX = mouseEvent.getScreenX() + offsetX;
                  double screenY = mouseEvent.getScreenY() + offsetY;
                  MouseButton button = mouseEvent.getButton();
                  int clickCount = mouseEvent.getClickCount();
                  boolean shiftDown = mouseEvent.isShiftDown();
                  boolean controlDown = mouseEvent.isControlDown();
                  boolean altDown = mouseEvent.isAltDown();
                  boolean metaDown = mouseEvent.isMetaDown();
                  boolean primaryButtonDown = mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown();
                  boolean middleButtonDown = mouseEvent.isMiddleButtonDown();
                  boolean secondaryButtonDown = mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown();
                  boolean synthesized = mouseEvent.isSynthesized();
                  boolean popupTrigger = mouseEvent.isPopupTrigger();
                  boolean stillSincePress = mouseEvent.isStillSincePress();
                  MouseEvent otherMouseEvent =
                      new MouseEvent(otherWebView, otherWebView, mouseEvent.getEventType(), x, y, screenX,
                                     screenY, button, clickCount, shiftDown, controlDown, altDown, metaDown,
                                     primaryButtonDown, middleButtonDown, secondaryButtonDown, synthesized,
                                     popupTrigger, stillSincePress, null);
                  otherWebView.fireEvent(otherMouseEvent);
                }
                else {
                  otherWebView.fireEvent(event.copyFor(otherWebView, otherWebView));
                }
                scrolling = Boolean.FALSE;
              }
            }
          });
        }

        private String createHtml() {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000000);
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("<nobr>%03d %2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s%2$s</nobr><br/>\n",
                                    Integer.valueOf(i), "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "));
          }
          return sb.toString();
        }

        private void setResultPanes() {
          setHtml(actualPane);
          setHtml(expectedPane);
        }
      }


      public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
      }

      @Override
      public void start(Stage dummy)  throws Exception {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        DifferencePanel differencePanel = new DifferencePanel();
        Scene scene = new Scene(differencePanel);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        differencePanel.synchronizeScrolls();
        stage.showAndWait();
      }
    }
```

This works for all input methods I'm interested in:

- Keyboard: PageUp, PageDown, all 4 arrow keys, "space bar" (same as PageDown) and shift-"space bar" (same as PageUp), Home and End
- Mouse wheel: RollDown and RollUp as well as shift-RollUp (scroll left) and shift-RollDown (scroll right)
- Using the mouse to click or to drag the scroll bar.
- Using the mouse to select text outside of the current view port.

Mirroring the mouse events has the added benefit that text gets selected in both WebViews.

Comment: `WebView` in Java 8 (at least up to version 1.8.0_92) does not always change to arrow cursor when entering the scroll bar.
With Java 9 (at least with version 9.0.4) this works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would post a comment, but sadly I did not have enough reputation.

Did you tried the following solution? Create listeners on value changed event, instead of binding. [Synchronizing two scroll bars JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563432/synchronizing-two-scroll-bars-javafx/46584523#46584523)